# Opening a file from resource monitor

Tags: windows-7, resource-monitor

Is there a way to open a file that is currently being written to or read from the resource monitor?

Resource monitor is great for finding these files, but often it takes a while to navigate to the path where they can be accessed.

Is there a way to do that (or open the parent directory)?

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), it is easier as you can copy the location of the file to the clipboard, then paste it into explorer to find it quickly.  It is a better tool all-round really.

Comment: How would I find out what file is being written to with this?

Comment: Along with millions of other things... How do I filter it?

Comment: That gets me all of the files that have been modified since procmon was opened. How do I get the last one (or the last few) that were modified?

Comment: In mine, they are sorted by total events.